# gets error when using try, but works fine without try

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this line in my code:

```
student.user.try(:services).try( :where, {course_id: params[:current_course]} ).try(:first)
```

It gives the following error:

```
undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x007fc35070da30>
```

But when I use it without try like this:

```
student.user.try(:services).where("course_id = ?", params[:current_course] ).try(:first)
```

everything is OK.

What's the problem with try?

Per your request adding the backtrace:

```
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb:36:in `try'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:89:in `method_missing'
  app/controllers/trainings_controller.rb:926:in `block in transfer_students'
  app/controllers/trainings_controller.rb:922:in `each'
  app/controllers/trainings_controller.rb:922:in `transfer_students'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:491:in `_run__1196091745092505907__process_action__2696008159292751787__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
```

Comment: Can you add the whole stacktrace of the error?

Comment: While I cannot confirm your issue, I also cannot understand the need for all of those calls to `try`. Is there a reason `students.user` would return `nil`? If not then you can remove all the calls to `try` (assuming `services` is an association of `user`). If so then I would just check that and move forward e.g. `course_services =  student.user.services.where(course_id: params[:course_id]) if student.user`

Comment: This seems to be the legacy behavior of `Object.try`, changed in Rails 4: "Object#try will now return nil instead of raise a NoMethodError if the receiving object does not implement the method" https://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-support-notable-changes

Comment: Nice catch @JakeWorth (should have noted the 3.2.8); although now I am more confused then ever. How does `services` sometimes return an `Array` and sometimes return an object that responds to `where` (AR::Relation?)? Maybe there is some delegation in Rails 3 that causes `try` to leak the internal records `Array` for the `AR::Relation` (might have to look into this)

Comment: @engineersmnky good questions. I don't have a reproducible environment for this. I'd be interested in the class of `services` in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Moving this to an answer since it seemed to be helpful.

Reading the release notes, this seems to be the legacy behavior of `Object.try`. It was changed to the current expectation in Rails 4:

> "Object#try will now return nil instead of raise a NoMethodError if the receiving object does not implement the method"

[Rails 4.0 Release notes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-support-notable-changes)